# C# Get a list of all runtime constructed classes of a generic class

Tags: c#, class, generics, reflection

I'm trying to make a list of all the runtime constructed classes created by a generic class. In other words, if I have a class:

```
public GenericCls<T> {
    public void Reset() { ... }
    ...
}
```

And I have code in various places like this:

```
GenericCls<int> gci = new GenericCls<int>();
GenericCls<String> gcs = new GenericCls<String>();
GenericCls<float> gcf = new GenericCls<float>();
...
```

Can I get something like this?:

```
Type[] allconstructed = GetAllConstructed(typeof(GenericCls<>));
```

which returns `{GenericCls<int>,GenericCls<String>,GenericCls<float>,...}`

The use case involves a generic allocator, that supports any type of object allocation (it's like `new XXX()`, but nicer to the garbage collector). I won't go into specifics, because it will just complicate the question. Basically, I will not know all the constructed classes at compile time, since the library is a dll intended to be used with a separate code project. So I will need some form of reflection that I can't seem to find on the interwebs.

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()` does not contain anything but the base generic class (i.e. `typeof(GenericCls<>)`)

`typeof(GenericCls<>).GetGenericArguments()` returns only Type "T", which is not only an invalid type, but entirely useless.

Is it even possible to find all constructed classes of a generic class if you only know the generic class' type? (`typeof(GenericCls<>);`) I'm not sure if "constructed" is the right word - I want to know either all the concrete generic-derived classes currently active, or all of these that will ever exist (not sure how C# handles generic construction behind the scenes).

Comment: @Ani, you should submit that as an answer, IMHO.

Comment: All of your unregistered accounts have been merged. Please, consider associating an OpenID with this one, or perhaps registering it if you don't want to use OpenID.

Answer (score 4):

@David Mårtensson: Your answer gave me an idea. I could make a static list of types in any non-generic class, and register each constructed class as it was constructed (when T is known).
i.e.

```
static public class ConcreteList {
    static public List<Type> concrete;
}
public class GenericCls<T> {
    static GenericCls() {
        ConcreteList.concrete.Add(typeof(GenericCls<T>));
    }
}
```

I checked it with `ConcreteList.concrete[x].GetGenericArguments()`, and it's working. Oh snap.

Comment: Look at how I edited your comment to see how to format code properly.  Code needs to be indented by 4 lines.  `<Code>` tags don't work like you think they would.

Comment: If you get it working, make sure to mark you answer as accepted so others will know which solution that solved it  :D

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a factory class to create instances, that way the factory class could keep a list of all created classes.